# Loopback is Baas or mBaas?

Tags: database, api, loopbackjs, mbaas

1. I am building a api on loopback. I was curious if loopback is a Baas or a mBaas framework. What I mean is will I face any problem if I would use it for my website builded in angularjs?
2. Will my api handle about 300req/s for all my requests?

Answer (score 0):

1. Loopback is mostly a generalized Baas framework. One of it's use cases is web applications that uses angularjs. I actually do use loopback as a backend for a Angular.js webapp.
2. Yes mostly, but that depends on your business logic, your servers, databases, server load and a lot of other factors.

Loopback builds an http rest API that can [get connected to databases or other rest or soap backends](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Connecting+models+to+data+sources). It also has a [few clients libraries](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Client+SDKs), which includes [plugin for angular resource](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK). You can also write your own connectors or client library.